# VLCJ getLength()

Tags: java, vlcj

I am using VLCJ library to play media files that are located on some web server. 
The only problem i have is how to get correct length of the media. I try to parseMedia but application hangs and if I call getLength on media player it returns 0.
Newerthless if using getPosition() and setPosition(float) it works ok, but this tells only % of media played not the actual length in seconds.

Is it possible to get correct length of streamed media and use the progress to go back and forward?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `getLength()` returns 0 it's because VLCJ doesn't know (or hasn't been told) how long the stream is, so it literally can't give you an accurate result!

The only way I can think of is if you have something else that works server side (perhaps a server instance of VLCJ) that sends the length of the file across separately?

Answer (score 2):

VLC has issues with getting the length of Theora/Vorbis data.
This has to be fixed by vlc developers, not vlcj.
They just dont bother right now...

Answer (score 1):

as i seen  in normal cases
 getLength() returns 0 when you trying to call immediately after play method.
but when u call it in another event/method it returns  correct length. 
for this i tried sleep for some milliseconds after play method/thread it returns correct length. then it may be take time to load all references. and now i don't know exactly what's behind this.?
 but as above streamed media i think correct outcome possible after completion the streaming .

Answer (score 1):

You can use this simple code:

```
int DurationInSeconds;
parseMedia();
DurationInSeconds = (int)(player.getMediaMeta().getLength()/1000);
```

if you want time before playing your media